# How can I play minecraft long distance

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an Android and my friend has an iPod, can we still connect to the same world at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No

Yes by connecting to the same WAN (Wide-Area Network) server. (e.g Mineplex)

And no if you want to use LAN (Local-Area Network. By using the same WI-FI, you can connect together, however your question states long distance)